# Distribution of # balls in each container (balls dropped randomly)

Tags: probability

I have the following problem. $N$ balls are dropped randomly into $M$ containers $C_i$, $i=1..M$ with probability $p_i$, $\sum_i p_i = 1$. Having dropped $N$ balls into the container, $c_i$ may hold the number of balls in container $i$. Let's denote the tuple $(c_1, ..., c_N)$ as a configuration. My question is how many configurations of $N$ balls in $M$ containers exist and what is their distribution?

Assume we have $N=5$ balls and $M=2$ containers. Each ball is dropped with probability $p_1, p_2$ into container $C_1,C_2$, respectively. $p_1 + p_2 = 1$. If I'm not mistaken, only the following configurations are possible:

$\Omega = \{(5,0),(0,5),(1,4),(4,1),(2,3),(3,2)\}$

How can I determine the number of configurations $|\Omega|$ and how can I determine the probability $Pr(\omega \in \Omega)$ of each such configuration?
I have to admit that so far I got nothing. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The last paragraph contradicts both your example and the characterization via the tuple $(c_1,\dotsc,c_N)$, which are appropriate for *indistinguishable* balls. If the balls are distinguishable, there are $2^5=32$ different arrangements in the example, with $2$ different choices for each of the $5$ balls.

Comment: @joriki: You are right. I needed a way to illustrate what I mean, say, to indicate that I'm interested in the probability of a configuration, not something else. I'd appreciate if you could help me improve the description.

Comment: I don't understand -- you've accepted André's answer, so apparently you did mean indistinguishable balls; all the rest of the question is consistent with that ; all you have to do now to fix it is to replace "the balls are labeled, thus distinguishable" by "the balls are indistinguishable".

Comment: @joriki: Done, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of configurations is the number of solutions od the equation $x_1+x_2+\cdots +x_M=N$ in non-negative integers $x_i$.  This is a standard [Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem (please see the Wikipedia article).  We can think of the number of solutions as the number of ways to distribute $N$ indistinguishable candies between $M$ children.  This turns out to be 
$$\binom{N+M-1}{M-1}.$$

For finding the various probabilities, one uses the [multinomial distribution.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) For instance, the configuration $(3,2)$ in your example has probability $\binom{5}{3,2}p_1^3p_2^2$. Here $\binom{5}{3,2}=\frac{5!}{3!2!}$. This is the ordinary binomial coefficient $\binom{5}{3}$.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about the multinomial distribution.